# How to create SlideShow plugin with jQuery keyframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

Given the example below:

```
$.keyframe.define([{
    name: 'myfirst',
       '0%':   {top:$("#test").innerHeight()*-1; left:0px},
       '100%': {top:$("#test").innerHeight()*-1; left:0px}
}]);
```

I want to make a plugin for slideShow, and would like to do it automatically. I need something like this example:

```
      var timeTransition = 10;
      var howManyImages= $("div.slider ul.slide li img").size();
      var timeIntervals= Math.round(100/howManyImages);
      var timeImages= 0;
      var t = 0;          
      var supportedFlag = $.keyframe.isSupported();

      $.keyframe.define([{
         name: 'myKeyframe',
        /*
           here, i wish to put a function like below where this result, will populate the $.keyframe.define parametrs.
          Should be that the next line would be for exemple:
        function () { here de result printed od function}?
        */
      for (i = 0; i < howManyImages; i++) { 

          tMin = t + timeIntervals;
          tMax = t + timeIntervals; 
          t+=timeIntervals;

          if(i==0) tMin=0;
          if(i==howManyImages) tMax=100;          

              tMin'%' : { margin-left:-timeImages'%'},
              tMax'%' : { margin-left:-temptimeImagesoImagens'%'}

          timeImages+=100;

      }

// end of $.keyframe.define([{
          }]);
```

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understood u! Can you be more clear? What do you not understand in a question?

Comment: its, ok. Thank u for it!

Comment: hi, i edited it. Can u please review?